# Arduino code not working

Tags: arduino

My plan is to make an adjustable speed strobe. I'm just learning to code and this is what I have so far.

```
int potentiometer_pin = A0;
int led_pin = 7;
int on_time = 100;
int analog_value_multiplier = 15;
int strobe_delay = 0;
int minimum_delay = 500;
void setup() {
  pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  strobe_delay = minimum_delay + analogRead(potentiometer_pin) * analog_value_multiplier;
  digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(on_time);
  digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(strobe_delay - on_time);
}
```

I have the LED + on digital 7 with a 220ohm resistor and the pot on analog 0, it is a 10K pot with one side hooked up to 5v+ and the other to ground.  My problem is that the LED stays on and turning the pot just changes the brightness.  Any help on what to do - not just a new code but what to do?  I want to actually learn how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

like david said, but I will add I think you want delay not delayMicroseconds.

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/delay

Answer (score 3):

Your speeds are all *WAY* too fast. Multiply all your delays by about 100. You've made a pulse width modulator.

Comment: well its definitely the speed, if i multiply the delays by 10000000, i can see the LED blink very fast. il have to keep experimenting.

Comment: @tomtortoise, there is a demo that uses the delay function I believe for arduino. If you load that up you should be able to get to the heart of your delays quickly. It is under examples > Basics > Blink. As you continue to progress into aruidno there is an [electronics stack exchange with quite a few questions about it](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino?sort=active).